# Find Href based on specific text in the name attribute of the a tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
<a class="cscore_link"  name="&lpos=house:schedule:final" href="https://www.url.com-2019-20">
```

There are multiple classes of `cscore_link` in the `html`, but the value of `name` attribute differs. I need to get the href value of all the `cscore_link` class where the value of `name` has a substring of `final`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Regex.

**Ex:**

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<a class="cscore_link"  name="&lpos=house:schedule:final" href="https://www.url.com-2019-20"></a>
<a class="cscore_link"  name="&lpos=house:schedule" href="https://www.url.com-2019-20"></a>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
print(soup.find_all('a', {'class':'cscore_link', 'name': re.compile(r":final\b")}))
```

**Output:**

```
[<a class="cscore_link" href="https://www.url.com-2019-20" name="&amp;lpos=house:schedule:final"></a>]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have Beautiful soup 4.7.1 or above you can use following css selector to find `name` contains `final`.

```
print(soup.select(".cscore_link[name*='final']"))
```

Or You can check name ends with `final`.

```
print(soup.select(".cscore_link[name$='final']"))
```